# How to reshape MLMultipArray in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I'm trying to colorize image using coreML, and the model always returns (1, 3, 256, 256) as result. I'm reshaping to convert it to (3, 256, 256) but not sure if it's correct way. Is there no way to pick only first element in array?

```
let input = try colorizer_coreInput(image_smallWith: resized)
let predicted = try colorizer_core(configuration: MLModelConfiguration()).prediction(input: input)
let array = predicted.colorized_small_image


var colori: UIImage?
try withExtendedLifetime(array) {
   if let reshapedArray = try? array.reshaped(to: [3, 256, 256]) {
       colori = createUIImage(fromFloatArray: reshapedArray, min: 0, max: 255)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following extension will provide what you need.  It's not a general reshape, but for your specific case of dropping a first dimension of 1, it will do the job.  It could be generalized to drop any of the dimensions so long as the dropped dimension size is 1, because that doesn't change the underlying memory buffer. The moment you drop a dimension whose size is larger than 1, things are more complicated.

Note there are two versions of the method.  The first one is fast, but unsafe if the source `MLMultiArray` goes out of scope, but since in your example it would be used in the scope of a `withExtendedLifetime` it's the one I'd use.

The second version is safe, but somewhat slower because it has to copy data into a newly allocated buffer.

```swift
extension MLMultiArray
{
    /**
     This version simply re-uses the existing `MLMultiArray`'s buffer, as a
     result  this version is very fast; however, if the original `MLMultiArray`
     is deinited this the new `MLMultiArray`'s buffer will be invalid.
     Therefore, ONLY use this when you can keep the original `MLMultiArray`
     alive for as long the one returned by this method is needed.
     */
    func dropFirstDimensionNoCopy() -> MLMultiArray?
    {
        guard shape[0] == 1 else
        {
            assertionFailure("Dropping non-1 dimension not supported")
            return nil
        }
        
        return try? MLMultiArray(
            dataPointer: self.dataPointer,
            shape: [NSNumber](self.shape.dropFirst()),
            dataType: self.dataType,
            strides: [NSNumber](self.strides.dropFirst()),
            deallocator: { _ in }
        )
    }
    
    func dropFirstDimension() -> MLMultiArray?
    {
        guard shape[0] == 1 else
        {
            assertionFailure("Dropping non-1 dimension not supported")
            return nil
        }
        
        var elementSize: Int
        switch dataType
        {
            case .double  : elementSize = 8
                
            case .float,
                 .float32,
                 .int32   : elementSize = 4
                
            case .float16 : elementSize = 2
                
            @unknown default:
                fatalError("Unknown MLMultiArrayDataType, \(dataType)")
        }
        
        let bufferSize = strides.first!.intValue * elementSize
        
        guard let newArray = try? MLMultiArray(
            shape: .init(shape.dropFirst()),
            dataType: dataType)
        else { fatalError("Unable to create MLMultiArray.") }
        
        memcpy(newArray.dataPointer, dataPointer, bufferSize)
        return newArray
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It works but when create UIImage with it, getting non-expected result. It was good with reshaping. Perhaps something was wrong.

Comment: @GPIT, since I don't have your functions, I couldn't test it, but found two errors in my answer that I have now fixed. Both had to do with `strides`.   The first was that I was using the product of strides for the allocation size in the safe version, but I should have just used the first stride.  That probably isn't what caused the failure.  You'd just get a buffer that was much larger than needed.  The other bug was likely the cause... I was using `shapes.dropFirst()` for the `strides` parameter when I should have used `strides.dropFirst()`.  I just typed the wrong thing.  Both are fixed now

Comment: wow, you're excellent, it works as well. thanks.

Comment: Another question for you so I'm using a Pytorch repo (https://github.com/Vadbeg/colorization-coreml) for image coloring, it works for small images but crashes for HD images because use lots of memory, while using CoreML(at this part: let resized = try colorizer_tail(configuration: MLModelConfiguration()).prediction(image: inputImage.pixelBuffer()!, ab: colorized).colorized_image). I have no idea to resolve this problem, Any idea?

Comment: I don't know, but if I had to guess, it's probably a matter of whether CoreML decides to do the computation in CPU using Accelerate, or in GPU via Metal.  The code I provide allocates using Swift `UnsafeRawBufferPointer.allocate`, which is basically doing a `malloc`, which will work fine in Accelerate, but for Metal, it will need an `MTLBuffer`.  The problem is that `MTLBuffer`'s are associated with the `MTLDevice` that's used to make them.  If you have just one GPU, you could just create the buffer using that device, and no problem.  But if you have more than one, which one is CoreML using?

Comment: And I don't know for sure that's the problem.  I have an idea that *might* work.  I'll update my answer with it.

Comment: So after looking into it a bit more it seems that `MLMultiArray`'s strides are, annoyingly, element strides not memory strides (ie, they're the number of elements, not the number of bytes).  I've updated the copying version to fix that, but I don't see how it would affect the non-copying version.   Which version were you using that crashed?

Comment: My updated version also uses MLMultiArray itself to do the allocation, in hopes that CoreML will better be able to cope with whether it wants to do CPU or GPU computation.